# Picking a given arm within a class

Tags: python, class

I am trying to understand the UCB Bandit that is written about in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449341330) book, and I'm running into a bit of trouble accessing a given arm of a multiarm bandit.

To put it in simpler terms: I have a class called NormalArm as follows:

```
class NormalArm():

  def __init__(self, mu, sigma):
    self.mu = mu
    self.sigma = sigma

  def draw(self):
    return random.gauss(self.mu, self.sigma)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.mu)
```

Now I can feed `NormalArm` two vectors of equal length `n`, `mu` and `sigma`, and that will create `n` "gaussian" arms that return a random value from a normal distribution with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma` when I access `.draw()`. I want to add a `__getitem__` attribute so that I can access the 2nd or 3rd arm only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you haven't got your types right. Your code cannot work.

You say that `mu` and `sigma` are *vectors*. But you pass them to `random.gauss()` that expects *scalars*. Still you insist on this thing being a sequence when you define `__len__()`.

What you want, I suspect, is something like this:

```
arms = NormalArms([0.0, 0.1], [1.0, 1.5])
assert len(arms) == 2  # hint: write tests right now!
second_gaussian = arms[1]  # gives you a gaussian(0.1, 1.5)
```

This class works the above way.

```
class NormalArms(object):
  def __init__(self, mus, sigmas):
    assert len(mus) == len(sigmas), "mus and sigmas lengths don't match"
    self.pairs = zip(mus, sigmas)

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    mu, sigma = self.pairs[index]
    return random.gauss(mu, sigma)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.pairs)
```

It was [not hard](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).